# Spring JPA using primary key within @Embeddable class

Tags: spring-data-jpa, composite-key

In my application i have a scenario to fetch data from entity based on give input code and date.
The combination of code and date will be unique and will return a single record.

Below is my entity

```
class JpaEntity
{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private id ;
        private String code;
        private Date date;
        private title;

        //Getters and Setters

}
```

I have tried below approcah by changing the entity.

```
class JpaEntity
{
        private String title;
        
        //Getters and setters
        
        @EmbededId
        private EntityId entityID
        
        @Embedable
        public static class EntityId implements Serializable{
        
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private id ;
            private String code;
            private Date date;
            
            //Getters and Setters
        
        }
}
```

I am using the entity to search based on code and date

```
public interface PersistentDAO extends JpaRepository<JpaEntity,String> {
{
    @Query("SELECT cal FROM JpaCalendar cal" + " WHERE cal.calendarId.currencyCode=:currencyCode "
            + " AND cal.calendarId.date=:date")
    Optional<JpaCalendar> findById(String currencyCode, Date date);
    JpaEntity findByID(String code,Date date)

}
```

But the JPA is throwing error saying Component Id is not found.
is it mandatory all the field in @Embedable are primary?
is it possible @Embedable class (composite id) contain the both primary and non-primay keys.

Since i am not supposed to change the structure of the table is there any way to achieve following:
Fetch record based on give code and date.
Insert new record where in id the primary key should be auto incremented

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Use  @Embedded & @Embeddable and don't use static class inside class

```
class JpaEntity
{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private id ;
        @Embedded
        private CodeDate codeDate;
        private title;
}
@Embeddable
class CodeDate {
        private String code;
        private Date date;
}
```

You can use Jpa method naming query and create a CodeDate object call like this

```
public interface PersistentDAO extends JpaRepository<JpaEntity,String> {
{
    JpaEntity findByCodeDate(CodeDate codeDate);
}
```

Comment: I need to fetch record Before i save new record everytime  to check if the records exists in database table. So to achieve uniquness i need to use combination of both code and date.

Comment: Thank you @Eklavya.I tried this but the exception is thrown

Comment: BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: sg.com.nets.rtgs.web.calendar.adapter.out.persistence.entity.CodeDate  must not have "@Id" properties when used as an "@EmbeddedId"

Comment: Use `@Embedded` not `@EmbeddedId`